# angular/material - how to get mat-toolbar shadow over the page content?

Tags: html, css, angular

I currently have a standard layout for my app, toolbar with a fixed sidenav and content section. I have since discovered that I can get the drop shadow on the toolbar with the class inclusion `mat-elevation-z4`, however I cannot seem to get the shadow to overlay the content section when I have scrolled down in the section itself.

I have also attempted to use the z-index to correct this...

`mat-toolbar` I gave `z-index: 2` and `<div class="container">` I gave `z-index: -1`

If somebody could give me some advice, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issue is because of the z-index. The toolbar is overshadowed by the content section which affects the box-shadow of toolbar. In order to keep the box-shadow visible, you need to give a higher z-index to toolbar (which you already did). But Z-index works on positioned elements, hence provide position to the  .mat-toolbar.

Example:

```
.mat-toolbar {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

**Predefined CSS classes**

The easiest way to add elevation to an element is to simply add one of the predefined CSS classes mat-elevation-z# where # is the elevation number you want, 0-24. Dynamic elevation can be achieved by switching elevation classes:

```
<div [class.mat-elevation-z2]="!isActive" [class.mat-elevation-z8]="isActive"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide some positioning for that element

```
 position: relative; or     position: absolute;
```

this is worked for me

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background: #3f51b5;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do both of the suggested solutions (Rahul's and K K's) in order to make it work:

1. I added to the `mat-toolbar` a `position: relative` and a `z-index` so the shadow will override the content below the toolbar:

```
.mat-toolbar {
    position: relative;

    z-index: 5;
}
```

2. I added elevation to the toolbar one of the "shadow" classes:

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z8" color="primary">
...
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="position: relative"` to the toolbar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18795728)

Comment: Why is not a valid answer?

Comment: be specific in your answer, and like said in prev link, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. After reading current one I have questions: what is "sidenav" here? Why adding this code it should help? Check other answers on this question, they have some effort to give clear answer